# Проблема с модулем aiogram на python 3.10 на Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, aiogram, vds

На данный момент я хочу запустить свой проект (бота для Telegram), но мой VDS выдает ошибку:

```
(myenv) root@abstracted-rest:~# python3 sss.py
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/sss.py", line 1, in <module>
   from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
   ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram' 
   (/root/myenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/__init__.py)
```

Что делать в таком случае?

Comment: 99% что вы перепутали версию aiogram

Comment: Допишите вашу установленную на VDS версию aiogram и инициализацию бота, с помощью [edit]